# Vim: SnipMate Plugin: how i can change a .snippet and update it on the fly?

Tags: vim, snipmate

does anyone know how to edit a dot snippet file and reload into (g)vim without closing and re-open the program? it would be great to do that with this excellent plugin.

greetings

Answer (score 41):

If you have the latest version of snipmate you can use the following command from vim to reload all the snippets `:call ReloadAllSnippets()` or better you can map it to a key

Comment: Thanks. just so its clear to others, at time of posting with 0.83 the latest version on vim.org, I had to go to the github dev version to get this function: https://github.com/msanders/snipmate.vim

Answer (score 8):

I am currently on a promoting tour for [UltiSnips](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2715) on StackOverflow. UltiSnips will watch your snippet files for change, so all you have to do is save your .snippets file and the changes are immediately available in Vim. There is also a handy :UltiSnipsEdit command that will open the correct snippets file right away.

A conversion script for snipMate snippets is shipped with UltiSnips, so switching is easy.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the following [discussion](http://code.google.com/p/snipmate/issues/detail?id=67)